# Exportaciones diarias en SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, sql-server-express

Tengo la siguiente consulta, anteriormente he hecho varias exportaciones de información desde SQL Server Standard o Enterprise, cuando son estas versiones de SQL no he tenido mayor problema ya que el Agente de SQL Server es la herramienta idónea para hacerlo a través de Jobs programados.

El problema en el que me encuentro es que debo de hacer una exportación diaria de información a través de un servidor con SQL Server Express que como sabemos carece de Agente de SQL Server. Entonces mi pregunta es cómo programar mis exportaciones para que se ejecuten diariamente con esta versión de SQL?

Comment: tal vez deberías desarrollar una pequeña app en el lenguaje que prefieras para que corra en el programador de tareas

Comment: No sé programar compañero, eso me limita bastante

Comment: Aqui te dejo un link al foro de MSDN en el que plantean un problema como el tuyo y mencionan herramientas que te pueden llegar a ser de utilidad.  
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/euanga/2006/07/20/faq-how-do-i-importexport-data-with-sql-express/
   
Suerte!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el Windows task scheduler, es un poco mas rudimentario que el SQL Agent, pero te va a servir para calendarizar tareas.